# Recursive/looping NSURLSession async completion handlers

Tags: swift

The API I use requires multiple requests to get search results.  It's designed this way because searches can take a long time (> 5min).  The initial response comes back immediately with metadata about the search, and that metadata is used in follow up requests until the search is complete. I do not control the API.

- 1st request is a POST to https://api.com/sessions/search/
- The response to this request contains a cookie and metadata about the search.  The important fields in this response are the `search_cookie` (a String) and `search_completed_pct` (an Int)
- 2nd request is a POST to  https://api.com/sessions/results/ with the `search_cookie` appended to the URL. eg https://api.com/sessions/results/c601eeb7872b7+0
- The response to the 2nd request will contain either:

  - The search results if the query has completed (aka `search_completed_pct` == 100)
  - Metadata about the progress of search, `search_completed_pct` is the progress of the search and will be between 0 and 100.
- If the search is not complete, I want to make a request every 5 seconds until it's complete (aka `search_completed_pct` == 100)

I've found numerous posts here that are similar, many use Dispatch Groups and for loops, but that approach did not work for me.  I've tried a while loop and had issues with variable scoping.  Dispatch groups also didn't work for me.  This smelled like the wrong way to go, but I'm not sure.

**I'm looking for the proper design to make these recursive calls. Should I use delegates or are closures + loop the way to go?  I've hit a wall and need some help.**

The code below is the general idea of what I've tried (edited for clarity.  No dispatch_groups(), error handling, json parsing, etc.)

Viewcontroller.swift

```
apiObj.sessionSearch(domain) { result in
  Log.info!.message("result: \(result)")
})
```

ApiObj.swift

```
func sessionSearch(domain: String, sessionCompletion: (result: SearchResult) -> ()) {

      // Make request to /search/ url
      let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in 
        let searchCookie = parseCookieFromResponse(data!)

       *********  pseudo code  **************
        var progress: Int = 0
        var results = SearchResults()

        while (progress != 100) {

          // Make requests to /results/ until search is complete  
          self.getResults(searchCookie) { searchResults in 
                progress = searchResults.search_pct_complete
            if (searchResults == 100) {
             completion(searchResults)
            } else {
              sleep(5 seconds)
            } //if
          } //self.getResults()
        } //while
     *********  pseudo code  ************
    } //session.dataTaskWithRequest(
 task.resume()
 }


func getResults(cookie: String, completion: (searchResults: NSDictionary) -> ()) 

      let request = buildRequest((domain), url: NSURL(string: ResultsUrl)!)
      let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
      let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in 
        let theResults = getJSONFromData(data!)
        completion(theResults)
     }
  task.resume()
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first off, it seems weird that there is no API with a GET request which simply returns the result - even if this may take minutes. But, as you mentioned, you cannot change the API.

So, according to your description, we need to issue a request which effectively "polls" the server. We do this until we retrieved a `Search` object which is *completed*.

So, a viable approach would purposely define the following functions and classes:

A protocol for the "Search" object returned from the server:

```
public protocol SearchType {
    var searchID: String { get }
    var isCompleted: Bool { get }
    var progress: Double { get }
    var result: AnyObject? { get }
}
```

A concrete struct or class is used on the client side.

An asynchronous function which issues a request to the server in order to create the search object (your #1 POST request):

```
func createSearch(completion: (SearchType?, ErrorType?) -> () )
```

Then another asynchronous function which fetches a "Search" object and potentially the result if it is complete:

```
func fetchSearch(searchID: String, completion: (SearchType?, ErrorType?) -> () )
```

Now, an asynchronous function which fetches the result for a certain "searchID" (your "search_cookie") - and internally implements the polling:

```
func fetchResult(searchID: String, completion: (AnyObject?, ErrorType?) -> () )
```

The implementation of `fetchResult` may now look as follows:

```
func fetchResult(searchID: String, 
    completion: (AnyObject?, ErrorType?) -> () ) {
    func poll() {
        fetchSearch(searchID) { (search, error) in
            if let search = search {
                if search.isCompleted {
                    completion(search.result!, nil)
                } else {
                    delay(1.0, f: poll)
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
    poll()
}
```

This approach uses a local function `poll` for implementing the polling feature. `poll` calls `fetchSearch` and when it finishes it checks whether the search is complete. If not it delays for certain amount of duration and then calls `poll` again. This looks like a recursive call, but actually it isn't since `poll` already finished when it is called again. A local function seems appropriate for this kind of approach.

The function `delay` simply waits for the specified amount of seconds and then calls the provided closure. `delay` can be easily implemented in terms of `dispatch_after` or a with a cancelable dispatch timer (we need later implement cancellation).

I'm not showing how to implement `createSearch` and `fetchSearch`. These may be easily implemented using a third party network library or can be easily implemented based on `NSURLSession`.

**Conclusion:**

What might become a bit cumbersome, is to implement error handling and cancellation, and also dealing with all the completion handlers. In order to solve this problem in a concise and elegant manner I would suggest to utilise a helper library which implements "Promises" or "Futures" - or try to solve it with Rx.

For example a viable implementation utilising "Scala-like" futures:

```
func fetchResult(searchID: String) -> Future<AnyObject> {
    let promise = Promise<AnyObject>()
    func poll() {
        fetchSearch(searchID).map { search in
            if search.isCompleted {
                promise.fulfill(search.result!)
            } else {
                delay(1.0, f: poll)
            }
        }
    }
    poll()
    return promise.future!
}
```

You would start to obtain a result as shown below:

```
createSearch().flatMap { search in
    fetchResult(search.searchID).map { result in
        print(result)
    }
}.onFailure { error in
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

This above contains complete error handling. It does not yet contain cancellation. Your really need to implement a way to cancel the request, otherwise the polling may not be stopped.

A solution implementing cancellation utilising a "CancellationToken" may look as follows:

```
func fetchResult(searchID: String, 
    cancellationToken ct: CancellationToken) -> Future<AnyObject> {
    let promise = Promise<AnyObject>()
    func poll() {
        fetchSearch(searchID, cancellationToken: ct).map { search in
            if search.isCompleted {
                promise.fulfill(search.result!)
            } else {
                delay(1.0, cancellationToken: ct) { ct in
                    if ct.isCancelled {
                        promise.reject(CancellationError.Cancelled)
                    } else {
                        poll()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    poll()
    return promise.future!
}
```

And it may be called:

```
let cr = CancellationRequest()
let ct = cr.token
createSearch(cancellationToken: ct).flatMap { search in
    fetchResult(search.searchID, cancellationToken: ct).map { result in
        // if we reach here, we got a result
        print(result)
    }
}.onFailure { error in
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Later you can cancel the request as shown below:

```
cr.cancel()
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!  I will look into Promises now as a better way to implement canceling.

Comment: @Eric If you are interested in _Scala-like_ Futures and Promises as shown above, take a look here: [Bright Futures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures) or, as an alternative [FutureLib](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/FutureLib). FutureLib also contains a separate and independent Cancellation lib. This Cancellation feature is useful to completely hide the underlying task, e.g. your client code don't need a reference to a  `NSURLSessionTask` object in order to be able to cancel a request. I'm the author of FutureLib.